# How to call get_hashes.bin RPC method?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc

From the documentation: https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_hashesbin

The description is not clear:

> block_ids - binary array of hashes; first 10 blocks id goes sequential, next goes in pow(2,n) offset, like 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 and so on, and the last one is always genesis block
>
> start_height - unsigned int

Can you give an example?

What does `block_ids` and `start_height` do?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the documentation maybe slightly outdated / misleading. Looking at the source code, the vector of block hashes, `block_ids`, would have the hashes (in binary form) starting with your local most recent few block hashes and ending with the genesis block's hash (so in reverse chronological order). `start_height` is used to specify the height of your most recent block hash.

Let's assume you have the block hashes in `block_ids` of [B10, B9, B8, B0] and `start_height` set to the height of B10 (where Bn is the hash of block n).

If the remote node you are calling the method on has blocks B0 through B2000, it would return, in `m_block_ids`, the hashes for blocks B1010 through B10 and return `start_height` as the height of block hash B1010. As you see, only a maximum of 1000 hashes are returned (think of it like a page of hashes), so you can then call the method again but this time with `block_ids` of hashes [B1010, B0] and `start_height` as returned from the last call's response `start_height` (so the height of block hash B1010).

Note, this method, and the other `.bin` methods, are binary encoded, not JSON.